# Customise Mail Components?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I wish to customise the mail components so I do:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

It generates a `html` and `markdown` folder under `views > vendor > mail`.

In each folder there is a file for each component. What is the difference between the `html` and `markdown` folders? Where should I modify each component?

Answer (score 1):

By default laravel uses html views unless you specify to use markdown in your mailables or notifications.

Comment: Thanks, why would one use markdown rather than html? I thought you could use markdown in the html emails anyway?

Comment: A lot of users are moving towards using markdown. Support was added to cater to the needs of those who wanted it. You cannot just add markdown to html and have it work, you need a markdown parser to convert it to html.

Comment: Yes I see a markdown parser in some of the html components. I'm still unclear as to what each set of views are though. When you say some people prefer to use markdown, do you mean as source, as either using markdown or html just outputs an html email? If this is the case, why are there two sets of views for each component (html and markdown)?

Comment: They use markdown to design the mail templates rather than using html. Markdown is easier to html in some regard. The built in components helps you create your own template where you might just need to make changes to some parts of the mail design for different mails. Having components let you expand the mails to different designs without having to rewrite them completely and just altering few components where needed.

Comment: Ok so if the markdown folder has components designed with markdown rather than html, how does Laravel (or I) select which component is used (markdown or html)?

Comment: You can specify that you want to use markdown in your mail or notification. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#markdown-mailables https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#markdown-mail-notifications

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesnt make sense in my project, im calling ->markdown on my view, yet it still renders the components inside the html folder?

Comment: I haven't used markdown emails yet so can't really offer help on that. But that isn't the expected result. You might want to dig a bit deeper into the docs or the api.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help anyway, I think I've found that the components under html are used to render the html file, whereas the components under markdown are used to render plaintext versions.